# Webpack multiple phases production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm developing React/Redux SPA frontend, and I wanna make build and deployment system with Webpack2. What should it have:
1. JS code splitting (vendor + my custom), minification, gzip, unique hashing, linking in index.html, deploying via ssh to server.
2. CSS extracting, merging into 1 file (vendor chunk also has some), minification, gzipping, hashing, uploading. Pretty straight forward.

The hard point is to link non-standard gzipped versions in html.
I set up pug for templating in html-webpack-plugin, but it doesn't accept anything other than .js .css extensions for linking. Which made me add add-asset-html-webpack-plugin, but this requires static naming(so I moved hashing to this stage) AND when run it requires this file to have existed, even if it is the last one in the plugins array(?). Which leads to a separate build. The question is in the second phase - what if I just wanna process these files with Plugins, not engaging entire build process again? It grabs my index.js from  entry point and starts chewing it again, while I just want to render a template and customs links. Anyway, I'm new to this Webpack madness and confused... Here's my setup:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require ('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var MergeFilesPlugin = require('merge-files-webpack-plugin');
var OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
var cssProcessor = require('cssnano');
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

const VENDOR_LIBS = [ ... ];

const config = {
entry: {
app: [ 'babel-polyfill', './app/index.js' ],
vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
},

output: {
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
publicPath: 'build/',
filename: '[name].js',
},

plugins: [

new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
  }
}),

new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    minChunks: Infinity,
    filename: '[name].js',
  }),

  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),

  new MergeFilesPlugin({
         filename: 'style.css',
         test: /\.css$/,
         deleteSourceFiles: true
     }),

     new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
       assetNameRegExp: /\.css$/g,
       cssProcessor: cssProcessor,
       cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: {removeAll: true} },
       safe: true,
       canPrint: true
     }),

new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  sourceMap: false,
  compressor: {
    warnings: false
  }
}),

new CompressionPlugin({
  asset: 'gzip/[path].gz[query]',
  algorithm: 'gzip',
  test: /\.js$|\.css$/,
  threshold: 0,
  minRatio: 0.8

 })

],
module: {
rules: [
  {
    use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'] },
    }],
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    use: 'json-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]',
        options: { limit: 40000 /*, outputPath: 'images/'*/ }
      },
      'image-webpack-loader'
        ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
     use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
       fallback: 'style-loader',
       use: [
        'css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[path][name]_[local]--[hash:base64:8]',
         {
           loader: 'postcss-loader',
           options: {
             importLoaders: 1
           }
         }

       ]
     })

  }
]
},
resolve: {
extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
},
devtool: false,
devServer: {

historyApiFallback: true,
contentBase: './app'
}
};

module.exports = config;
```

AND injecting part I invoke afterwards:

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var AddAssetHtmlPlugin = require('add-asset-html-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
entry: './app/index.js',
output: {
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
publicPath: 'build/',
filename: 'index.js',
},

plugins: [
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'app/index.pug',
  inject: false
}),

new AddAssetHtmlPlugin({
filepath: 'build/gzip/vendor.js.gz',
includeSourcemap: false,
hash: true
})

],
module: {
 rules: [
  {
    use: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'] },
    }],
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
  {
    test: /\.pug$/,
    loader: 'pug-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]',
        options: { limit: 40000 /*, outputPath: 'images/'*/ }
      },
      'image-webpack-loader'
        ]
   }
  ]
},
resolve: {
extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
},
devtool: false,
devServer: {

historyApiFallback: true,
contentBase: './app'
}
};
```